# FB Photo Application and Album creation linkage

Tags: facebook, photo

I have a sample application that uploads photos to a user's FB account.  Of course, FB creates an album with the name of the app and loads the photos in that album.

If the user changes the name of the album, then FB still uploads photos to the same album (although the album has been renamed).

How does FB know which album belongs to my application?  There are no obvious signs of linkage between my appid and the album ids / links that FB creates for the album.

Thanks in advance.

SS

Answer (score 0):

There's likely an association on the backend between the `AppID` and the `AlbumID`.

Comment: Colm Doyle - thanks for your response.  However, my problem remains as follows - I am trying to upload photos to the same album without creating duplicates.  I need to check if a given photo exists before I upload it.  Without knowing which album to check in, I have to do too much checking.  Hopefully someone knows what the linkage is.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to know your app albumID.

Three suggestions for you:

1. Allow the user to choose the album to upload the photo to. You can do this by uploading to albumid/photos instead of me/photos.
2. If you want to know your album, once you have uploaded one photo, you can use the returned ID along with FQL to query the photo table. This works independently of album and will let you query on object_id and return the album object id. e.g., SELECT album_object_id from photo where object_id = '(yourobjectid)' Store this, it won't change.
3. Upload a tiny test photo and use the method from 2 above. This will let you know your current album id. Then delete the tiny test photo.

Hope this helps.